# Starting increment isn't appearing (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

```
organisms = int(input('Enter the starting number of organisms:' ))
increase = float(input('Enter the average daily increase (percentage): '))
days = int(input('Enter the number of days to multiply: '))

print('Day Approximate              Population')
for x in range(days):
    print(x + 1)

for y in range(1, days):
    organisms += organisms * increase
    print(organisms)
```

The given inputs will be:

- Organisms: 2
- Daily Increase: .3
- Days to multiply: 10

So basically, it will print 2.6 all the way down to 21. I would like to start at 2 (given organism) and print all the way down to the 10th day multiplied by the organisms.

Comment: Couldn't you simply print before adding? I.e. switch the last two lines of code. And adjust the range as needed. By the way: If increase is in percent, shouldn't you divide it by 100 before using it to increase organisms?

Comment: I wanted to do it like that but I thought there was an actual "proper way". And regarding about the percentage, thanks.